# Cannot download PNG from canvas in javascript

Tags: html, canvas, download, fabricjs

I created a canvas using fabric.js to freehand some doodles. I want to download the canvas when I click a button. I tried 4 different methods of doing this in Chrome and I get no download and nothing on my console showing any errors. I have this first method working in another app I wrote with no issue, but I can't get it working here. Any ideas?

The first method, which I have working perfectly in another app (works on the same browser) I wrote is here:

```
function saveImage(e) {
this.href = canvas.toDataURL({format: 'png',quality: 0.8 });
this.download = 'frontside.png'
}
```

https://codepen.io/morrowsend/pen/JgmBQj

Comment: All functions except the first one worked for me in your pen. You just don't have those functions attached to the buttons.

Comment: Forgive my stupid...  Thank you.